# go: exposed alias struct can't assign to inner struct literal

Tags: go, struct, model

I arrange my models in this way:

- projectDir

  - main.go
  - models

    - models.go
    - modelA

      - modelA.go
    - modelB

      - modelB.go

In `main.go`:
    package main

```
import (
    "test.local/projectDir/models"
)

func main() {
    modelA := models.ModelA{
        FieldA: "xx",
        FieldB: models.ModelB{
            FiledC: "yy"
        } // here will raise a error: cannot use models.ModelB literal (type models.ModelB) as type modelB.ModelB in field value
    }
}
```

In `models/models.go`:

```
package models

import (
    "test.local/projectDir/models/modelA"
    "test.local/projectDir/models/modelB"
)
type ModelA modelA.ModelA
type ModelB modelB.ModelB
```

In `models/modelA/modelA.go`:

```
package modelA

import (
    "test.local/projectDir/models/modelB"
)

type ModelA struct {
    fieldA string
    fieldB modelB.ModelB
}
```

In `models/modelB/modelB.go`:

```
package modelB

type ModelB struct {
    fieldC string
}
```

As the error point out, the struct type is different. Is there a better way to organize the models?

Comment: What exactly in the error message is unclear? Note that you do **not** alias `modelB.ModelB` to type `models.ModelB`. You define a **new** named type. Named types like this are convertable to each other, but (as they are different types) not directly assignable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory: you are trying to assign the wrong value (`models.ModelB`) to a `ModelB.modelB` struct.
You can easily solve this issue by importing the correct package:

```
import (
    "test.local/projectDir/models/modelB"
)

func main() {
    modelA := models.ModelA{
        FieldA: "xx",
        FieldB: modelB{
            FiledC: "yy",
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: This will solve the error, but now I have to import all `models` one by one.

Comment: This is how Golang project structure works. If you don't want import all packages one by one you can put all your model inside only one package splitted in multiple files